# Boy at relative's house, pill makes him immune to mold-like monster

Tags: story-identification

So around 20 years ago I read a book and hope to find it again. I have very slight memory of what happened except one scene. This will be paraphrased.

A young boy is at a relatives house. The house goes dark and he gets a flashlight from on top of the fridge. He finds a pill on the table and takes it. Then there is a mold like monster that tries to get him but the pill made him immune to it.

That's all I can remember.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [Interstellar Pig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_Pig), by William Sleator, a scene pretty close to the end.  The mold-like monster is an alien lichen that is constantly devouring everything it touches, and one of the "players" in the game that's trying to get the Piggy.  The pill is one of the cards he happened to draw when the aliens decided to include him in the game, and it was mysteriously provided just after the aliens withdrew until the game was on (he didn't even know what he was immune to until the lichen failed to eat him as expected).

He also draws/gets some kind of electro-whip, and a disguise device which he uses to hide in the lichen from the other three aliens (a spider, a floating octopus, and a mer-man) when they show up as well.